# Optimized pattern searching algorithm in Python

Tags: python, algorithm

I need to search a regular expression pattern from a huge list of file names. So, time complexity is very important factor for me. Currently, I am using this code to find the pattern:

```
for item in mylist:
    if reobj.match(name):
        // do some stuff and return the result
```

So, I think reobj.match call is taking O(n^2) time. Can anyone suggest me any other pattern searching algorithm in python to make the operation faster?

Please note that the list is not sorted, so can't do a binary search here.

Few other ideas I have is related to maintain an index on file names. But again the concern there is with the regular expression patterns. How can I index on patterns?

Comment: what is it that you need to match? Maybe something other then a regex would be possible?

Comment: If the regex contains any constant strings you could do a simple substring check on those constants before applying the regex.

Comment: No the regex essentially contains file names and my task is to match all those entries where this file name is present as a sub string.

Comment: And what makes you think that this is ` O(n^2) `?

Comment: I am honestly not sure about the time complexity of reobj.match call. Normally, sub string search algorithms would take O(n^2) time unless its KMP algorithm. Please correct me if am wrong.

Comment: It's not worth debating O(n^2) or not. Does `reobj.match` work fast enough for you? If you want to see its O, run a few subsets and measure it. You might get both O and startup time.

Comment: No, its not working fast enough for me..that's why I am looking for an alternative solution. Can you pls suggest me some ideas on indexing on file names given i have to search a pattern ?

Comment: Have you tried `re.compile()`?  It may be more performant for you: https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.compile